# Google Assistant installation via python - setup.py install for grpcio ... error

Tags: python

I am *trying* to install GoogleAssistant for my PC using python. I am a beginner at coding in Python. So, I am basically using instructions from various sites. (esp - https://www.lifewire.com/google-assistant-on-windows-4628292 )

I have tried updating python version through 
"python -m pip install --upgrade pip."

```
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    ----------------------------------------
*ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\S K CHOUDHARY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\S K CHOUDHARY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gr2pj17q\\grpcio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\S K CHOUDHARY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gr2pj17q\\grpcio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\S K CHOUDHARY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-n9m9wxyy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

What does the above error mean ? How can I fix it ?

*WARNING:*

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (19.3.1)
```

**Do look at the WARNING. It says that I ought to have version 19.3.1 but upon running upgrade the very same cmd shows that I am already using the latest version 19.3.1. How is this possible?**

I am facing a lot of confusions. Can anyone ALSO recommend some websites for beginners for installing GoogleAssistant on PC. I have tried Github but haven't been able to comprehend it.

Comment: Have you possibly installed both Python3.7 and Python3.8 at some point?

You could be calling on two different installations of Python

Comment: I installed only python 3.8 but upgraded to version 19.3.1 through cmd.

Comment: Just to make sure, go to C:\Program Files, check how many folders start with 'python'. You definitely have python37, make sure you don't have any others (python38, python2x... etc)

Comment: I have only one '**Python3.7**' named folder.What else ?